# What is the best way to remove infs or NaNs in R?

Tags: r, nan, inf

I'm having some trouble with infs or NaNs in my files. What is the best way to remove them using R?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove them" - remove rows containing those values?  To do anything else, you would need to show us how those values got generated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to get rid of `NaN` and `Inf` of `-Inf`, you're better off using `is.finite`.  In the context of a data frame, you could eliminate the offending rows with:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
  dat <- data.frame(
   x1 = c(1, 2, NA, NaN, 3, Inf),
   x2 = c(1,2,3,4, NaN, -Inf)
 )
dat
#>    x1   x2
#> 1   1    1
#> 2   2    2
#> 3  NA    3
#> 4 NaN    4
#> 5   3  NaN
#> 6 Inf -Inf
dat %>% filter(if_all(everything(), is.finite))
#>   x1 x2
#> 1  1  1
#> 2  2  2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that `!is.na()` and `!is.nan()` don't solve the whole problem:

```r
dat %>% filter(if_all(everything(), ~!is.nan(.x)))
#>    x1   x2
#> 1   1    1
#> 2   2    2
#> 3  NA    3
#> 4 Inf -Inf
dat %>% filter(if_all(everything(), ~!is.na(.x)))
#>    x1   x2
#> 1   1    1
#> 2   2    2
#> 3 Inf -Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!is.nan()`.  Here is an example:

```
x1<-sample(1:50, 10)
x2<-sample(c(0, 5,4), 10, replace=TRUE) 
x3<-x2*0.5
x4<-x1/x2 #will generate Inf because we are dividing by 0 
x5<-x1/x3 #will generate Inf because we are dividing by 0
x6<-x5-x4 #will generate NaNs because we are subtracting Inf from Inf
x7<-x6[!is.na(x6)]#Will remove all NaN elements
```

Comment: I was able to address this issue. But I have another trouble: "FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in true_divide".

I would like to know how I can address this in r studio?

Comment: Do you think you could post a reproducible example of that error?

Comment: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mtag.py", line 1577, in <module>
    mtag(args)
  File "mtag.py", line 1458, in mtag
    save_mtag_results(args, res_temp, Zs, N_raw, Fs, mtag_betas, mtag_se, mtag_factor)
  File "mtag.py", line 875, in save_mtag_results
    out_df['mtag_beta'] = mtag_betas[:,p] / weights
FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
Analysis terminated from error at Tue Apr  5 18:58:21 2022
Total time elapsed: 14.0m:48.79s

Comment: By reproducible example, I meant something I can run on my machine to get the same error.  Here's a link for a guide on making these. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, Sean, I'm unable to share the reproducible example dataset.